# Bad formatting in JSON ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I am having some odd problems with data coming back from a jquery Ajax call that I cannot figure out.

I have a c# asp.net web page that binds a valid JSON data blob to the UI with client side JavaScript on page load. This part works just fine. I set up a jquery Ajax post back that returns the same data and calls the same JavaScript data binding method, and this throws an error when I attempt to bind the data. It looks like the JSON written to the page on load is properly treated as a JSON object, but the data returned by the ajax call isn't.

Here is the ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: 'POST',
data: "{'move_list': '1-2,3-2'}",
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 
url: 'Puzzle.aspx/ProcessMove',
complete: OnComplete,
success: function(data){BindData(data);},
error: OnError
});
```

Here is a sample of the JSON data that is being processed:

```
{"game": [{"x":0,"y":0,"color":"Blue"},{"x":1,"y":0,"color":"Green"}]}
```

Here is the code that loads the data when the page is first loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// method returns JSON object above.
// client side code appears like this:
// BindData({"game": [{"x":0,"y":0,"color":"Blue"},{"x":1,"y":0,"color":"Green"}]});

BindData(<%=Game.SerializeToJson()%>);  

</script>
```

and finally, the JavaScript binding function:

```
function BindData(data) 
{
    try
    {
       document.getElementById("square1").className = data.game[0].color;
        // much more of the same....
    }
    catch(exception)
    {
        alert(exception.message);
        // error thrown here is 'data.game is undefined'.
        // the data object is being treated like a string and not a JSON object.
        // so the indexing into the object fails.
    }
}
```

I have double checked the JSON data with several online JSON parsers, and the data is formatted correctly. The server side code generates the same output in either case.

I tried to change the jquery Ajax call to...

```
success: function(data){BindData(JSON.parse(data));},
```

...to see if it was just treating the returned data as a string as opposed to a JSON object, but that just generates this message:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
BindData(JSON.parse(data));
```

Completely stumped by this one. I have been reading everything I can find and trying all sorts of things, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: what is error when don't use JSON.parse? Is success callback firing? Or your OnError?

Comment: when there is no JSON.Parse call, an exception is thrown in the BindData function, 'data.game is undefined'. This suggests to me that the Json data is being passed back as a string (because the data parameter is populated, but data.game is undefined.)

Comment: can inspect the full request in browser console and see exactly what is sent back..look in network tab. Can also log response to console using `console.log(data)`

Comment: I was looking at the returned data in the console and the ajax call returns this: {"d":"{\"game\": [{\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"color\":\"Blue\"}]}"}, which is kind of interesting. It looks like there is an extra 'd:' node that wraps the string being returned.

Comment: I found the problem: the 'd' node is a node that ASP.NET wraps around JSON to prevent XSS attacks. There is a great article about it here: http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/. so the fix is to add in a data filter function call in the JS to remove the extra node.